# "ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'list' with no type" error

Tags: c++, list

I keep getting the following errors on every line containing `list<string>` below:

- `ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'list' with no type`
- `expected ';' before '<' token`

```
#ifndef __REGNAMEGENERATOR_H
#define __REGNAMEGENERATOR_H

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

#define Max_reg_Num 1000

using namespace std;

class RegNameGenerator{
private:
    int intRegNumber;
    int realRegNumber;
    list<string> UsedIntReg; // error
    list<string> UsedRealReg; // error

public:
    RegNameGenerator();
    ~RegNameGenerator();
    string generateIntReg();
    string generateRealReg();
    list <string> getUsedIntReg(); // error
    list <string> getUsedRealReg(); // error
    int getIntRegNum();
    int getRealRegNum();
};

#endif
```

Comment: You should also see: [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to include header `<list>`:

```
#include <list>
```